# Why Program Files (x86)

Tags: windows, 64-bit

What was the reason for naming the 32-bit Program Files on a 64-bit system as "Program Files (x86)" and giving 64-bit applications the regular "Program Files"?

One would think that doing the opposite (ie, having a "Program Files (x64)") would perhaps make more sense.

Comment: XP? Vista? 7? .

Comment: 7 is what I'm on but I'm under the impression the dual Program Files folders are present on other 64-bit versions of Windows as well.

Comment: @Seth indeed they are

Comment: @BloodPhilia Thought so, hence I didn't tag any specific version of Windows.

Comment: **This is NOT a discussion forum**. This question was asked in the past and closed because there is no **official** technical document that can be provided to support any answer. Therefore it will remain close. Furthermore, Super User is not for discussions like this, it is a Q&A platform. Please treat it as such and all users should read and understand the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq), and also check regularly for when policy changes are made.

Comment: @Diago My apologies, I did not wish to prompt a discussion. I had hoped there existed a definitive answer. As it is, your statement that there is no official documentation as a means to an answer is as good an answer as I could ask for. It was my hope that such documentation did exist I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Because 64-bit is standard on a 64-bit system and it's supposed to run 64-bit programs whereas 32-bit is deviant on such a system and 32-bits is "emulated". Thus the deviant application folder is appended (x86)

Comment: I get that 32-bit applications are 2nd-class on a 64-bit version. I suppose I'm just not convinced that that outweighs 'moving' the install location of old applications to a location which is different than where they used to be.

Comment: Software writers must follow guidelines, if those writing installers don't check up the location in the registry then its their problem.